# SELECT query giving unique constraint violation in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have this below Hibernate Select query where I am fetching the results which have the given name:

```
Query selectQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select aw from TableName aw WHERE lower(name)='"+"NAME".toLowerCase()+"'",TableName.class);

List entityList = selectQuery.getResultList();
```

But this query gives me :
ORA-00001: unique constraint (Constraint_Name) violated Exception.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

How could a SELECT query give Unique constraint exception? Is it because of the Unique Index on the table?
Below is the full stack trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1419)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3001)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1389)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1474)   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1441)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CRESTPRD.NAME) violated
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 117 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I have shared @SamuelPhilipp

Comment: So what table does `CRESTPRD.NAME` constrain???

Comment: I reviewed your query and doubt if there is something wrong with that.


"select aw from TableName aw WHERE lower(name)='"+"NAME".toLowerCase()+"'"

"aw" is the table alias and did you mean to place aw.*?

Between, it is a good practice to use prepared statements for passing query param values rather than string concatenation. String concatenation lead to SQL injection that you are aware of. Just thought to mention here. Thanks.

Comment: I was passing query param into the query earlier, thought of trying it this way but no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all for your response. I resolved this issue by removing the Unique constraint and index from the table. I doubt it was due to the lower() function. As after lower() these 2 rows will have the same name. After removing the Unique constraint now I am checking at the Application level to avoid the duplicate names.
Thanks again.

Comment: Do not do this. This is a workaround and ignores the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

The **constraint violation exception belongs to an earlier executed insert statement** from your code! But **Hibernate cached the insert!** It did not forward it to the database - but it executes the cached insert just before the select! And therefore fails - looking like the select had a problem.

So the insert before was the root cause and contained values hurting that constraint.

**Long version:**

I stumbled upon this article with similar problem with Hibernate, JavaEE - in which I am not (yet) an expert:

- I had a loop inserting rows into a table.
- The first iteration in the loop was successful.
- But in the second I got a ConstraintViolation exception (in my case it was a unique index over two columns).

While debugging I found out, that it happened just at executing such a simple JQPL "`select count(*) from ... where ...`"!
There is no trigger in this query, nothing (in my case it was even the same table involved than for the insert statement in the loop).

That I am sure, what Hibernate does - I enabled the logging of SQL to the console with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in the file called `application.properties` to see what SQL is created by Hibernate.

And at the point where the select query was executed with the next debugging step:

1. The constraint exeception occured
2. The log showed *only* an `insert` statement! That from the first loop iteration, because it was missing in the console log before! And I checked the parameters of the first loop iteration with the table content and yes, it would hurt that constraint! Hurray. I found it.

Your Hibernate configuration/settings are such (like in my case), that you executed an `insert` statement in your code somewhere before the `select` statement.
But Hibernate cached the execution of the insert - it did not yet execute any insert towards the database!

Finally at executing the select statement Hibernate somehow sees the need to execute the cached insert statement now really in the database - and this fails with the ConstraintException, what is returned to you as (mind blowing) error.

Like this pseudo code, that is called during execution of the select query:

```
   private ResultSet executeQuery(String sql = "select ...") {
       if (areThereCachedHiberateQueries()) { // yes, an insert
           if (isItNowNecessaryToExecuteTheseCachedQueriesWithDatabase()) { // yes says Hibernate
               executeAllCachedQueries(); // here the cached insert produces the constraint violation error
           }
       }
       if isSelectStatement(sql) {
           return executeQuery(sql); // we do not even reach this code here!
       } else {
           cacheQuery(sql); // insert, delete, update
           return null;
       }
   }
```

Some members pointed out, that the stack trace shows a failed insert statement. But they assumed, that the select statement somehow contains itself a trigger/... what @user3262365 denied.

Here I showed that the select did not cause the insert. The insert command was already cached by Hibernate - and finally executed as "preparation" for the select towards the database - but the insert failed with a constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

Your column `CRESTPRD.NAME` has a unique constrained defined, which means every value can only occur once in this column. If you are trying to insert a new entry with a value, which already exists in that column you get a `ConstraintViolationException`.

So this seems to be a problem in your data model. Either remove that unique constraint from that column to be able to have a value multiple times in that column or add every value just once to prevent that error.

Comment: It is just a simple SELECT query. there is no where I am inserting into the table.

Comment: Have you tried your select without the `lower()` function?

Comment: Yes, without the lower() function it works fine. That's why I doubt if it Could it be due to the lower() function? As after lower() these 2 rows will have the same name.

Comment: Do you really need that `lower()`? As alternative you can lower the values in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this exception is not due to your select statement. I'm not sure there's even any way for a select to cause this exception. Rather, I think somewhere you are doing an insert of a row that already exists in the table. There's this in your stack trace:

```
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
```

Maybe somehow it's being done by Hibernate? I know nothing about Hibernate, really. The docs suggest the `EntityInsertAction` interface is, not surprisingly, for inserting records.

Comment: A SELECT, obviously, won't directly cause such a constraint violation, but I can picture at least a couple ways to cause this to happen. For instance, if in the SELECT statement a function was invoked which performed an INSERT or UPDATE, that could do it. If fine-grained auditing was enabled for the particular table and column being SELECTed, the FGA handler proc could perform an INSERT or UPDATE which could raise such a constraint violation. And I wouldn't be surprised to discover there are others, but I'm just not up to the task of thinking of them tonight. :-)

Comment: You're right, I was thinking more along the lines of triggers. But if you try to do an insert or update inside a select, you get `ORA-14551 cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`, so it has to spawn an autonomous transaction.

Comment: There is no where I am doing an insert explicitly. However there are 2 rows with the same NAME but in different cases. Could it be due to the lower() function? As after lower() these 2 rows will have the same name. Could it be the issue?

Comment: No, you generally cannot get this error with a `SELECT`. Could Hibernate be doing something you're not aware of?